# Why isn't my Foresty Farm activating this Buildcraft gate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-buildcraft, minecraft-forestry

I've constructed a brand new Forestry Farm, it's completely empty of items but is powered and has water:

[image: Empty Forestry Farm UI]

I've set up a hatch fed from some barrels to feed items into it, using gates to determine which items to request from the barrels:

[image: Barrels feeding Forestry Farm]

The main gate adjacent to the farm is configured as follows:

- If Fertiliser is less than 25%, activate red pipe wire
- If Soil is less than 32, activate blue pipe wire
- If Germlings is less than 10%, activate green pipe wire

However none of the gate pathways are activated:

[image: Gate configuration]

**Why isn't the gate working as it's supposed to?** All the conditions are met but none of the pipe wires are being activated.

Comment: Are the mods mentioned anywhere to be compatible with each other? Also, you apparently use more mods than those two, so it might be helpful to know the full list.

Comment: @FabianRöling They are compatible, Forestry adds those gate options to Buildcraft and the Farm accepts water and power inputs via Buildcraft pipes and puts the output into Buildcraft item pipes. The other mods are JABBA for the barrels and NEI on the inventory, they won't be causing any conflicts with either.